# Old MOTU 828 Mk1 on a modern system

Tags: audio-interfaces, motu

I'm brand new to pro audio recording, and I'm putting together my system right now.  I'm interested in buying a MOTU 828 Mk1 interface in order to pipe 4 XLR mics through the 828, through firewire, into the Mac, into some software VSTs, then back out through firewire to the 828 and output to some live monitors.  In other words, the whole point is to apply some VST effects to some Microphones.

Since the 828 Mk1 is fairly old hardware, I just want to check with anyone who has used this device to make sure that there won't be any hangups using it in the scenario I described on a current Mac with Firewire.

Comment: You may run into some slight latency issues depending on the drivers and VSTs.

Comment: http://www.gearslutz.com/board/so-much-gear-so-little-time/635281-motu-828-mk1-still-worth.html

Comment: I can't speak for your particular issue, but while trying to use an old Motu TimePiece on Win 7 64bit, just installing the drivers crashed my computer.  This probably won't help, but it may speak to the compatibility of older Motu products with newer machines.

Comment: I used an 828 mk1 on a 64-bit windows install with no issues.  I just used ASIO4All

Answer (score 2):

I'm using an 828 mk1 on my mac book pro and it runs fine. It only has two mic pre's on the unit and you may have some latency issues running VSTs live.

Answer (score 0):

I used an 828 mk1 with no issues (on Windows) for some time.  A little bit of latency for sure.

It was actually old enough where the one firewire port on it was loose enough where I very easily plugged the firewire cable in upside down and fried the chip.  So that's that...